# RavenDB Service Session.Query not returning results

Tags: session, oauth, ravendb

I have a RavenDB Service instance set up on localhost:8080 and am using the OAuth plugin to store a simple user document for authentication. I am using a guid for the id and the users email as the name. The following code is functioning properly to store the user

```cs
public AccountUserDocument CreateUser(RegisterModel model)
{
    using (IDocumentSession session = DataDocumentStore.Instance.OpenSession())
    {
        Guid userId = Guid.NewGuid();

        session.Store(new AccountUserDocument
            {
                Name = model.Email,
                Id = String.Format("Raven/Users/{0}", userId),
                AllowedDatabases = new[] { "*" },

                Email = model.Email,
                FirstName = model.FirstName,
                LastName = model.LastName,
                FacebookId = 0,
                Expires = DateTime.Now.AddMonths(1),
                AccessToken = string.Empty

            }.SetPassword(model.Password));

        session.SaveChanges();

        return session.Load<AccountUserDocument>
                       (String.Format("Raven/Users/{0}", userId));
    }
}
```

and returns a valid user object. However, when i call

```cs
return session.Query<AccountUserDocument>()
              .Customize(x => x.WaitForNonStaleResults())
              .Where(x => x.Name == email)
              .SingleOrDefault();
```

I get nothing. It had been working a week ago but now it just doesn't. If I open up RavenDB studio, I can see the user and the name is exactly how I am entering it (i have even copy and pasted it into the text field).

[image]

I have tried stopping and restarting the service hoping that would solve the problem but it did not.

I was wondering if someone could point me in the direction of how I might debug what is going on here. The full code repository can be found here

https://github.com/jamesamuir/MVC_Facebook_Auth

if anyone is inclined to download it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Couldn't find any related code in the link you provided.  Wrong link?  Or your repo not updated?  I don't see anything immediately wrong, except be careful not to call `WaitForNonStaleResults()` in production.  Also, by calling `.Load()` in the same session, you're not really getting it from the server.  It's cached in the session.

Comment: So after digging around a bit I found that I can save a simple document to the service and query it just fine. However, it seems that when I use the Authentication Bundle, it returns null when I query by name. I created a simple project to demonstrate this behavior. It can be found at https://github.com/jamesamuir/RavenConnTest.git
I am using the 992 build of the server 
and 1.0.960 of the client and authentication bundle, installed via nuget

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I see a lot of things wrong with the code sample you provided - such as mismatched versions of client and server.  Also, the Authentication Bundle was a 1.0 feature that has been deprecated in 2.0 which is almost final, so you're writing code you will eventually have to replace.

But to answer your question, the specific reason that you can't get results from your query is that you chose to use a document key starting with "Raven/", which is the convention for RavenDB system documents - which don't get indexed.

If you remove "Raven/" from your id, it will work.

Also, you should not be using `.WaitForNonStaleResults()` - that's only for unit tests, and is dangerous in production.  If you really feel like you need to wait, use `.WaitForNonStaleResultsAsOfNow()` - which is safer because it provides a cutoff.

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply! I was following an Authentication Bundle tutorial 
http://mytechworld.officeacuity.com/index.php/2012/07/authentication-and-authorization-in-mvc-projects-using-ravendb/
which seemed to work for me and I tried tweaking it a bit. The .WaitForNonStaleResults() was in there as a test to ensure that i was working with an up to date document set when I queried. 
I am wondering, however, if you could provide me with a link regarding the deprecation of the Authentication Bundle as I can't seem to find any articles stating such. Thanks again.

Comment: There's not a whole lot documented yet.  I've [requested](http://issues.hibernatingrhinos.com/issue/RDoc-81) they add better documentation around authentication options.  It was removed on [september 27](https://github.com/ayende/ravendb/commit/70933e047cba50b560098b3b3d341a902cf0ed0e) and [api keys](https://groups.google.com/group/ravendb/browse_thread/thread/d87a67d0b1a516c) was announced around the same time.  You might want to look at the Asp.Net auth provider from [Raven.Contrib](https://github.com/ravendb/ravendb.contrib), but it was just recently added and isn't well documented yet.

Comment: Thanks again, I really appreciate the follow up.